# Implication of two inequalities

Tags: analysis, inequality

Let $\rho= k/x$, and $\rho_0= k/x_0$, with $k=constant$, $\rho>0$, $\rho_0>0$ and $k>0$

Is this implication true? And if so, why?

$$
\forall \varepsilon > 0 \; \; \mbox{if } \; |\rho-\rho_0|\leq \varepsilon \; \; \rightarrow \; \; |x-x_0|< c \varepsilon
$$

With $c=constant$.

Comment: I bet no, I think your implication means $x(\rho)=k/\rho$ is Lipschitz continuous on $(0,\infty)$, but we know $1/\rho$ is not even uniformly continuous on $(0,\infty)$

Answer (score 1):

It is false. Take $x= ax_0$ for some $a \ne 0$. For $x_0$ sufficiently large, you have
$$|\rho-\rho_0| = \left| \frac{1-a}{a} \right| \cdot \left|\frac{k}{x_0} \right| \leq \varepsilon$$
while
$$|x-x_0| = \left| a-1 \right| |x_0| \uparrow + \infty$$